# Qlist Struct append not accessible in QT 4.8 in release mode

Tags: c++, qt

When I am appending a struct to a QList the data is seen is not accessible in QT in release mode, when I try accessing it, it gives me segmentation fault.
Note: This works fine in Debug, maybe due to debug mode setting some default values.

```
struct ListStruct
{
    unsigned char name[4];
    unsigned int mysize;
};

QList<ListStruct> myList;
ListStruct data;
QString temp("ABCD");
strncpy((char *) &data.name, temp.toLocal8Bit().constData(), 4);
tmp.mysize= 10;
myList.append(tmp);
```

Then MyList show's data is inaccessible, in short it has garbage values.

This is a simple code, but it does not work, have tried to debug the append but doesn't show where the copy is failing.
The tmp structure populates just fine.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Instead of summarizing ala "in short it has garbage values" please show the code that makes you come to that conclusion

Comment: Does 'name' need to be null terminated?